# Aspect ratio of image in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to get an image on the bottom right corner. I can get it easily but the problem now is to change the size of the image. I want to preserve the ratio of image while setting either height or width.

```
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                    <Image Source="party.png"
                           HeightRequest="100"
                           VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                </StackLayout>
```

With the xaml above, I set height and width is being changed accordingly. But, when I add `HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"` in the image i lost the aspect ratio.

How can I put image at bottom right with preserving the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HorizontalOptions="End"` , then image will at bottom right with preserving the aspect ratio .

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <Image Source="Saimiri_sciureus.jpg"
            HeightRequest="100"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Aspect="AspectFit" />
</StackLayout>
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: didnt work in my case. image came back to its original size

Comment: @KhimBahadurGurung Maybe it's because of image .Could you share the Imgae link here , I will download it to test in my local site .

Comment: i solved it by setting height and width manually,  couldnt do in the way I wanted

Comment: @KhimBahadurGurung Glad you have solved that ! Remember to share the solution in answer and mark that :-)

Comment: What I did is not the way I wanted to do and is not the answer of this question. I just worked around to solved the issue. :D. I will surely post the answer if I found one

Comment: @KhimBahadurGurung Okey , if possible you can share the image link here , I will check this image in my local site .

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
<Image Source="party.png"
        HeightRequest="*"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        Aspect="AspectFit" />
```

And that will keep the aspect ratio.